# Align image below text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I align an image below text, without the image going to the right of the text?

I'm using [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) to display the icons/links in columns. But below that, I want the image to be centered below the paragraph of text.

I have tried using `clear` but no change.

```css
a:link {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 75%;
}
a:visited {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 75%;
}
a:hover {
  color: #9700bd;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 75%;
}
a:active {
  color: #9700bd;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 75%;
}

footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
footer div div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
footer > div {
  /*margin-left: 25%;*/
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
  <div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://instagram.com/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://vine.co/u/1269681750234615808" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vine" aria-hidden="true"></i> Vine</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://youtube.com/channel/UCZhk1PN4RzBXe63bqg0GtHw" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i> YouTube</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://twitch.tv/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitch" aria-hidden="true"></i> Twitch</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://soundcloud.com/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud" aria-hidden="true"></i> SoundCloud</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/ItzJavaCraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-reddit-alien" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reddit</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://github.com/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i> GitHub</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/6125445/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" aria-hidden="true"></i> Stack Overflow</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://jsfiddle.net/user/ItzJavaCraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-jsfiddle" aria-hidden="true"></i> JSFiddle</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="footer" style="clear: right;">Oh, hello there. My name is Java. No, not the programming language! Well, this is awkward. Not much else to be said... uhm... enjoy your stay, I guess!</p>
    <a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk">
      <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="ItzJavaCraft" class="footer" />
    </a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ItzJavaCraft/t886rerp/)

Comment: By wrapping the text in a paragraph above the image?  You'll need to show us some code if we are to be able to help with your specific issue.

Comment: @HaukurHaf Updated with some code

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue: [Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/y0jjahf3/).

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/gjye4cbr/  There must be some other CSS code which you have not shown us which is causing your issue.

Comment: @showdev Here is my site if it is any help http://itzjavacraft.tk

Comment: @HaukurHaf https://jsfiddle.net/ItzJavaCraft/t886rerp/

Comment: @showdev https://jsfiddle.net/ItzJavaCraft/t886rerp/

Comment: @ItzJavaCraft - This has nothing to do with the markup you posted in the original question?  Something entirely different.

Comment: It looks like your footer is using [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), i.e `footer > div { display: flex; ...`.

Comment: @showdev I am using the flexbox to keep the list of links in line, do you know how I could fix the problem without having to remove this, or perhaps another way I could keep the links the way they are and fix this issue?

Comment: One solution is to apply flexbox only to the div that contains the links, as opposed to every div in the footer.

Comment: @showdev This worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest solution I can think of is to apply Flexbox only to the `<div>` that contains your icons/links. That way, the `<div>` below will remain "un-flexed" and will stack as you expect:

```css
footer {
  text-align: center;
}

#footer_links {
  display: flex;
}
#footer_links div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
#footer_links ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
  <div id="footer_links">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://instagram.com/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://vine.co/u/1269681750234615808" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vine" aria-hidden="true"></i> Vine</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://youtube.com/channel/UCZhk1PN4RzBXe63bqg0GtHw" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i> YouTube</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://twitch.tv/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitch" aria-hidden="true"></i> Twitch</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://soundcloud.com/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud" aria-hidden="true"></i> SoundCloud</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/ItzJavaCraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-reddit-alien" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reddit</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://github.com/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i> GitHub</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/6125445/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" aria-hidden="true"></i> Stack Overflow</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://jsfiddle.net/user/ItzJavaCraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-jsfiddle" aria-hidden="true"></i> JSFiddle</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <p>Oh, hello there. My name is Java. No, not the programming language! Well, this is awkward. Not much else to be said... uhm... enjoy your stay, I guess!</p>
    <a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk">
      <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="ItzJavaCraft" />
    </a>
  </div>
</footer>
```